# How to get 2 structure from values and create JSON in Helm?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

**Values**

```
a :
  b:c
  d:e
  f: 
    g:h
```

I have **config map**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: myName
  labels:
data:
  myDaya.cfg: |-
    {{ toJson .Values.a }}
```

**The result is**

```
myDaya.cfg: {"b":"c", "d","e", "f":{"g":"h"}}}
```

Now I added another values to **.values** file

```
a1:
  b1:
    c1: d1
```

The "a1" must be in different structure
The new **.Values**

```
a :
  b:c
  c:d
  e: 
    f:g
**a1:
  b1:
    c1: d1**
```

The new config now should include 1 json also with value a1 meaning

```
myDaya.cfg: {"a": { "b":"c", "d","e", "f":{"g":"h"}} ,"b1:{"c1":"d1"}}
```

Could you advise me how I can change the config map ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helm has [several functions for manipulating dictionary objects](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#dictionaries-and-dict-functions) (which come from the [Sprig template support library](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/dicts.html)).  These include a [`merge`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#merge-mustmerge) function that combines multiple dictionaries into one.

The one trick with the dictionary functions is that they generally work by mutating an existing dictionary object.  This is in contrast to most of the other Helm/Sprig functions, which act on immutable objects.  So to use `merge` without accidentally changing `.Values`, you need to create a new empty dictionary (with [`dict`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#dict) and then `merge` the various sub-dictionaries into it.

```yaml
data:
  myDaya.cfg: |-
{{ merge dict .Values.a .Values.a1 | toJson | indent 4 }}
```

Or, if you want to keep the top-level dictionary keys, you can use `dict` to directly construct the result dictionary:

```
{{ dict "a" .Values.a "a1" .Values.a1 | toJson | indent 4 }}
```